# Aligning 2 DIVs on top on each other in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

So I'm using bootstrap to create an index home page
what I'm trying to do is basically align in the center 2 divs on top of each other :
I have a container-fluid
then a row with 2 cols: in 1 of the cols I have 2 divs that I want to be aligned in the center ( both horizontally and vertically ), 
( code is shown below )

here's an illustration :
[what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITY9.png)

green is the container-fluid ||
red and blue are the divs I want to be aligned || an orange is a login form I want to add later on

my code goes like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid mainwrapper p-2">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">

        <div>
           <img src="pictures/logooo.png" class="my-2" alt="uc2">
        </div>

        <div>
           <a class="rounded shadow-sm bg-white biorHv px-3">Faculté NTIC | Departement de Scolarité</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    <!-- Login form here -->

    </div>      
</div>  
</div>
```

here's a real picture of the problem

i want the green logo and the writing with the white background to be aligned in the center of the left column

[real problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY7r8.png)

[what I realy want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgHOe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-center class to divs you want to align center. Shown in below code

```
<div class="col">

    <div class="text-center">
    <img src="pictures/logooo.png" class="my-2" alt="uc2">
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
    <a class="rounded shadow-sm bg-white biorHv px-3">Faculté NTIC | Departement de Scolarité</a>
    </div>


</div>
```

This will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

add these steps:

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="pictures/logooo.png" class="my-2" alt="uc2">
</div>
```

**css**

```
.col {
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just give "col-md-6" to with column and a "text-align:center;" (horizontal align), and "margin:0 auto". Try this.

```
<div class="container-fluid mainwrapper p-2">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center;">

<div style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div>
        <img src="pictures/logooo.png" class="my-2" alt="uc2">
        </div>

        <div>
        <a class="rounded shadow-sm bg-white biorHv px-3">Faculté NTIC | Departement de Scolarité</a>
        </div>

<div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-md-6">

    <!-- Login form here -->

    </div>


</div>  
</div>
```